# creating an autoplay slideshow using Fancybox3

Tags: jquery, html, css

trying to change slideshows previously run in Fancybox2 to Fancybox3. Janis recently helped the change for youTube video now I'm trying to do the same for my slideshows. I have used this code before:

```
    // fancybox for images
```

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
        padding : 0,
        autoPlay: 'true',
        playSpeed: 4000,
        closeBtn: true,
        arrows:true,
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.4,
                css: {
                    'background': '#50a3e2'
                }
            }
        }
    });

As before for me I need the background colour, no border image with the box shadow and the old style close button and previous / next buttons as in the sprite image you referenced for me before.
Most grateful for any help given.
Example of current slideshow here:
https://www.whiteshepherdsnz.com/orchardgrovePuppies.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
        afterLoad: function() {

            if (!$('.fancybox-button--play').hasClass("fancybox-button--pause")) {
                $('.fancybox-button--play').trigger('click');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm none the wiser. At least I understood the FB 2 way of doing things and could find examples to learn from. This version seems to require high level of Jquery knowledge of which I have none. Does this provide the previous / next buttons and close button. The version I was given to run youtube videos required more functions and css to reproduce what I have now - see [link]https://www.whiteshepherdsnz.com/NewSite/page1.html